# I keep getting error 0x800f081f while trying to run DISM with /RestoreHealth option (Windows 10 Pro)

Tags: dism

This problem is on Windows 10 Pro.

I know this question has been posed lots of times in lots of places, but I now need to ask for help on this while I still have a few tufts of hair left.

I have been getting random BSODs recently, and after a number of memchk's and scandisk's etc., I ran DISM with /restorehealth option. After getting to 100% the process eventually fails with

```
Error: 0x800f081f
The source files could not be found.
```

I have visted many sites in an attempt to fix this, including around Stack Overflow several times. Nothing has worked for me. I have tried

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
```

followed by

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyzeComponentStore
```

The /AnalyzeComponentStore fails every time with **Error: 2**. DISM /restorehealth still does not work.

I have tried downloading and mounting the latest Windows 10 image ISO to extract the WIM file (for Windows 10 Pro) from the install.esd file. I have tried using the ESD file directly. The commands I use are:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:WIM:C:\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:ESD:G:\sources\install.esd:6 /LimitAccess
```

I have even tried setting a group policy. *Nothing* seems to work. **sfc /scannow** returns no faults at all.

Can anyone help me solve this problem please? Thanks in advance for any advice you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything with this. I found errors in the CBS.log file that showed a prior update package had a missing or corrupt manifest. This causes DISM and normal Windows Update to fail. Even chkdsk /r followed by a restore to a previous checkpoint did not work - the System Restore tool threw an error.

I finally gave up messing about and decided the best course of action was to reinstall Windows 10. I downloaded Microsoft Media Creation Tool and updated using the latest ISO image. It took nearly 6 hours but now the health of my PC appears to be restored.

The reason I chose this action was because of an interesting article I read [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/369656/dont-click-check-for-updates-unless-you-want-unstable-windows-10-updates/). Its 18 months old but I think it could still be relevant, especially as this is exactly what I've done a couple of times recently.

The upshot is 'never click *Check for Updates*' as this may harm your PC. If Microsoft mess up a pre-release update and you install it, there is usually no way back to recover, and no way forward other than to install Windows afresh.

We live and learn!